# How to fix "Cannot operate on a closed database." while using dumdata in Django

Tags: django, sqlite, shell

does anybody knows how to fix this problem?
`sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.` 
I just want to finish the command to create a dump of my models.
`python manage.py dumpdata > .\fixtures\goods\cats.json` 
I dii a little research, it gave me information that this error is connected with wrong encoding in db. Any ideas?

I have tried to recreate a db twice, tried to force db work with utf8 encoding using parameters with dumdata